# Conditional Binomial variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Consider the following:
$$ T= \binom{Y} {n/2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{Y}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{Y-\frac{n}{2}},$$
where $Y$ is a Binomial random variable with sample size $n$ and probability $p$. I noticed that this looks like the Binomial pmf, is it right to consider $T$ as the pmf of  $X \mid Y$ where $X$ follows a $B\left(Y,\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Comment: No, if $y$ is known, so is $T$,and there is no distribution. And the unconditional distribution of $X$ has little to do with a Binomial.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I edited my question, what about now?

Comment: No significant change.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\mid Y~\sim~\mathcal{Bin}(Y, \tfrac 12)$, then $$\mathsf P(X{=}n/2\mid Y) ~=~ \dbinom {Y}{n/2}\,\left(\dfrac 12\right)^Y ~\mathbf 1_{n\in 2\Bbb N_y}~\mathbf 1_{Y\in \Bbb N}$$